# Can Net Shield ability be triggered "in response"?

Tags: android-netrunner

When runner has [Net Shield](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/net-shield-core) installed, can they wait until they are about to receive net damage before they decide to trigger its ability?

If the answer is "yes" (or even "no") could you please also explain how it falls into the timing structure of Android: Netrunner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android Netrunner anything with "prevent" or "avoid" is triggered outside the normal timing rules as the thing it wants to prevent or avoid is about to happen.

This means whenever you are about to take net damage for the first time in a turn, you can pay 1C to activate net shield and prevent 1 of that damage.

From the rulebook ([PDF](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/ADN01_Rules_ENG_Lo-Res.pdf)) page 21:

> **Prevent or Avoid**
>
> Some card abilities use the words “prevent” or
>   “avoid.” Prevent or avoid effects are the only effects which can
>   disrupt another effect. A prevent or avoid effect states what it is
>   preventing or avoiding, and an effect that is prevented or avoided is
>   not resolved. Prevent or avoid effects can be triggered whenever the
>   effect they are preventing or avoiding is resolving.